# Adding directions to my Google map

Tags: google-maps

I am using the following code to view two markers on a map.

```
<script
src="http://maps.google.com/maps?file=api&v=2"
type="text/javascript"></script>
<script type="text/javascript">
//<![CDATA[
//globals
var bounds = new GLatLngBounds();


function initMap() {
if (GBrowserIsCompatible()) {
var map = new GMap2(document.getElementById("map"));
var title = "Map";
map.addControl(new GSmallMapControl());
map.addControl(new GMapTypeControl());
var point = new GLatLng(&P1_START_LOCATION.);
var marker = new GMarker(point);
map.addOverlay(marker);

var point2 = new GLatLng(&P1_END_LOCATION.);
var marker2 = new GMarker(point2);
map.addOverlay(marker2);

bounds.extend(new GLatLng( &P1_SOUTH., &P1_WEST. )); 
bounds.extend(new GLatLng( &P1_NORTH., &P1_EAST. )); 
map.setCenter(bounds.getCenter(), map.getBoundsZoomLevel(bounds));



}
}
//]]>
</script>
```

Thee marker and boundary values here come from the directions API.  I'm now wondering how to add the blue directions line between the two and I'm a bit stuck.  I have tried adding the following:

```
var directionsDisplay;
    var directionsService = new google.maps.DirectionsService();

 directionsDisplay = new google.maps.DirectionsRenderer();

      var request = {
          origin:point,
          destination:point2,
          travelMode: google.maps.TravelMode.DRIVING
      };
      directionsService.route(request, function(response, status) {
        if (status == google.maps.DirectionsStatus.OK) {
          directionsDisplay.setDirections(response);
        }
      });

        directionsDisplay.setMap(map);
```

I'm not getting any results and am doing this a bit blind to be honest.  Any help or pointers in the right direction would be appreciated!

EDIT: Here is my code now - I have a map with two markers on but I haven't got the directions drawn yet.

```
<script
src="http://maps.google.com/maps?file=api&v=3"
type="text/javascript"></script>
<script type="text/javascript">
//<![CDATA[
//globals
var bounds = new google.maps.LatLngBounds();
var directionsDisplay;
var directionsService = new google.maps.DirectionsService();

    var startPoint = new google.maps.LatLng(37.7699298, -122.4469157);
var endPoint = new google.maps.LatLng(37.7683909618184, -122.51089453697205);


function initMap() {
if (google.maps.BrowserIsCompatible()) {
var map = new google.maps.Map2(document.getElementById("map"));
var title = "Map";
map.addControl(new google.maps.SmallMapControl());
map.addControl(new google.maps.MapTypeControl());
var point = new google.maps.LatLng(&P1_START_LOCATION.);
var marker = new google.maps.Marker(point);
map.addOverlay(marker);

var point2 = new google.maps.LatLng(&P1_END_LOCATION.);
var marker2 = new google.maps.Marker(point2);
map.addOverlay(marker2);

bounds.extend(new google.maps.LatLng( &P1_SOUTH., &P1_WEST. )); 
bounds.extend(new google.maps.LatLng( &P1_NORTH., &P1_EAST. )); 

map.setCenter(bounds.getCenter(), map.getBoundsZoomLevel(bounds));

    directionsDisplay = new google.maps.DirectionsRenderer();

  var request = {
      origin:point,
      destination:point2,
      travelMode: google.maps.TravelMode.DRIVING
  };

  directionsService.route(request) 
  directionsDisplay.setDirections(response);

  directionsDisplay.setMap(map);

}
}
//]]>
</script>
```

Comment: You are using the [Google Maps Javascript API v2](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/google-maps-api-2), that version of the API has been deprecated since 2010, turned off and replaced with a wrapper for v3.  **It should not be used for new code**.

Comment: Ok, thank you.  I have changed the v2 in my code to v3 and it still works - I presume I need to do more than this to upgrade to the latest API calls?

Comment: https://developers.google.com/maps/articles/v2tov3

Answer (score 0):

Well, I got it working using something along the lines of the following:

```
 <head><meta http-equiv="content-type" content="text/html; charset=UTF-8"/> 
   <title>Google Maps JavaScript API v3 Example: Directions Complex</title> 
   <script type="text/javascript" 
           src="http://maps.google.com/maps/api/js?sensor=false"></script></head>

<body>

<div id="map" style="width: 400px; height: 300px;"></div> 

   <script type="text/javascript"> 

   var directionsService = new google.maps.DirectionsService();
   var directionsDisplay = new google.maps.DirectionsRenderer();

   var myOptions = {
     zoom:7,
     mapTypeId: google.maps.MapTypeId.ROADMAP
   }

   var map = new google.maps.Map(document.getElementById("map"), myOptions);
   directionsDisplay.setMap(map);

   var request = {
       origin: '&P1_ORIGIN.', 
       destination: '&P1_DESTINATION.',
       travelMode: google.maps.DirectionsTravelMode.DRIVING
   };

   directionsService.route(request, function(response, status) {
      if (status == google.maps.DirectionsStatus.OK) {


         directionsDisplay.setDirections(response);
      }
   });
   </script> 
</body>
```